# Is it possible to have something like: MyClass<T extends Enum<T> : implements IMyInterface>

Tags: java, interface, enums

I want to have an abstract class that depends on a generic parameter `T` which extends `Enum<T>`. The thing is, that I want that `enum` to implement an interface too. Is it possible to write something like that?

```
public interface IMyInterface {
  // ..
}

public enum MyEnum implements IMyInterface {
  // ..
}

public abstract class MyClass<T extends Enum<T> : implements IMyInterface> {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `<T extends Enum<T> & IMyInterface>`

Comment: Omg I've been trying for an hour now to get that right. Thank you, that is it. Do you want to provide an answer or should I delete my question?

Comment: well, I posted it as an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should work:

```
<T extends Enum<T> & IMyInterface>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not say like this. Because extends is the key used  for both extends and implements in generics.

you can say like this

```
   public abstract class sdfsadf<T extends Enum<? extends IMyInterface>> {
   }
```

Here T will be enum as well as it will Implements IMyInterface.

Comment: No, this is not the same as I want. I want an `enum` which implements `IMyInterface` and *not* that the generic type of the `enum` does that. There's a difference.

Comment: Ya. It will work. It means T should be a enum and as well as it should implements IMyInterface.